# Downgrade from Fedora Rawhide to Beta

Tags: fedora

Currently I running Fedora Rawhide. I don't clearly understand how it happened but I tried update Fedora 22 to beta (Gnome 3.18 is so sweet thing for me).

Is it safe to downgrade to beta version? I have a lot of packages from Rawhide repo. And how can I do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, it's really hard; rpm isn't designed to go backwards. If you want to try, I think this should do it:

```
sudo dnf --releasever=23 --allowerasing downgrade fedora-release
sudo dnf distro-sync
```

**Note that this is dangerous** — the `--allowerasing` option definitely allows you to shoot yourself in the foot, and doing a distro-sync that large just plain might not work.

I might instead consider just staying on Rawhide through the Fedora 23 cycle. We (disclaimer — I work on Fedora!) occasionally cause some problems there, but if you follow blogs like Kevin Fenzi's [This Week in Rawhide](https://www.scrye.com/wordpress/nirik/category/rawhide/) you can generally be aware when they're likely to happen and be careful with updates.

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot! I'll try to stay on Rawhide :) But I encountered problems with wifi modules so I using a Rawhide with kernel from F22. o_O